# Bootstrap alertinfo getting merged with button in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have provided the code snippet
here i want to display the marque below logo but it is covering the whole header.
[Visit here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEL3ROM7KLDG)

Comment: what is covering whole header?

Comment: 1) your logo in not loading. 2) marquee is showing under the log. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%;` on `alert-info` div it will work fine that you want.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
You missed at least a container-fluid style declaration. See your snippet updated, here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEL4BAHI14YZ.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="bootstrap-overrides">
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
        <img width="300" class="img-responsive" style="height: 120px; float:left" src="images/logo.jpg" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">BUTTON</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="frm" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="color: red">
            <marquee>Welcome To IDB WEB APPLICATION. All (*) Fields Are Mandatory</marquee>
        </div>
     </form>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want buuton on the right side of logo and below there should be marquee

Answer (score 0):

**Updated- Just wrap your header and alert-form individually inside a `container-fluid` with a `row`. Thats the best solution using bootstrap.**

> below is the wokring code. For logo I am using dummy image

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="header">

        <img width="300" class="img-responsive" style="height:120px; float:left;" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">BUTTON</button>
        <!--- Remove this inline style style="height: 120px; float:left" -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <form id="frm" runat="server">
      <div class="alert-info" role="alert" style="color: red">
        <marquee>Welcome To IDB WEB APPLICATION. All (*) Fields Are Mandatory</marquee>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if i remove style then height will be set to auto and i dont want that. also buton should be displayed on right side of logo